# LoadError cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2 Ruby 5.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[enter image description here][1]I have tried multiple solutions for this but I still haven't make it work.

Here is my Gemfile

```
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
```

I have tried changing it to ~> 0.3.18 but it still does not work. I'm still new to this framework and this problem stops me from progress

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIHiz.jpg

Comment: can you add more of the stack trace?

Comment: Apparently, you're on Windows. What version of ruby are you using? Have you tried other versions?

Comment: try putting bundle exec before the command http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, make sure that you're using Ruby 2.3, because there is no mysql2 binary available for Ruby 2.4 on Windows yet.

For more info : https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/861